# python 'set', 'for' and 'if' in one line, how to interpret this one liner?

Tags: python, syntax

python is very flexible and strong, but its syntax still a bit challanging for me.

I still have some difficulties to interpret some compact statement.

Below given one liner a bit confusing for me? How should I interpret this statement.

```
print list(set([x for x in outliers if outliers.count(x) >1]))
```

Comment: `[x for x in outliers if outliers.count(x) >1]` is a list comprehension. `list(set(...))` is just normal syntax.

Comment: This should be written as `[k for k, v in Counter(outliers).items() if v > 1]` anyway; see [the `Counter` documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) for its purpose.

Comment: And `list(set([...]))` takes the resulting list, converts it to a set and back to a list, which removes duplicates at the cost of potentially changing the order.

Comment: It makes a new list out of a set. The set itself is made from the list comprehension `[x for x in outliers if outliers.count(x) >1]`, which is presumably the list of elements in outliers that appear in outliers more than once. The whole thing adds up to 'give me a list of elements that appear in outliers more than once'.